# Microsoft Botframework and Data Protection

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using MS Bot Framework with Directline for webchat and our client has raised an issue about Data Protection i.e. the user is sending personal data via a Microsoft api.

I don't really know how to reply to this since (a) Pretty much every bot uses a cloud service if you want any sort of assistance and (b) I assume that Directline does nothing with the data and it is purely a conduit, but I don't know that for a fact.

Was going to post on bot builder github issues, but they say it's just for bugs and suggested that I come here. I am looking for some clarification (or a contact at MS) about the privacy and data protection of the conversations if you are using Microsoft's bot framework with any one of their connection services - particularly Directline.

Thanks,
Jarrod

Answer (score 0):

Our official handling terms are listed under the Bot Framework Terms of Service and Privacy statement found on the Bot Framework portal. Are there specific questions your customer has?

-jim

Comment: Can you edit and include a link (preferably fwlink), Jim?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it looks very generic about MS as a whole. The question they have is specifically regarding the Directline service, the bot framework and what it does with the conversation data i.e. is Directline purely a conduit, or is there some sort of data collection happening? Users are sending information that can identify them personally, and the round trip via Microsoft's servers in a different continent is making the client nervous. Looking for a bit of reassurance about the data protection now, and what will happen if they take it to the next level and start using Luis.